# I am facing issue in jmeter

Tags: automation, jmeter, performance-testing

When I record and run the test in login transaction one request is failed.i check that request I found in post data session id keep on chenging.i did correlation for that Id .after I want to replace the variable name insted of that Id.but it not replace. Because that Id is not there any subsequent requests and any parameter value undre the requests.how I need to handle that Id how to replace it... please help me for the above issue
**Note**: I search that ID in view results tree it showing that Id passing in 3subsequent requests

Comment: Need more info on how it is implemented. Can you share the screenshots of the correlation and the View results tree?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you **really** "did correlation for that Id", i.e.

1. Double check that the variable has the anticipated value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) combination
2. Make sure that the placement of the [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) performing the correlation is correct as according to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) the Post-Processor is applied to:

   - One Samples only if it's placed as a child of this sampler
   - All the Samplers which reside at the same level (or lower) with the Post-Processor

   so it might be the case you're overwriting the variable with the empty value somewhere else.